# How to stop adblock plus blocking images in HTML page

Tags: image, adblock

I am building a simple HTML page with some images, my FireFox has Adblock Plus—recently installed— and it blocks these images. I look at other similar pages on the net and they are not blocking images so why is it blocking mine?

I do not want visitors to my page to not see images if they happen to have Adblock installed in FireFox.

Some advice to allow images to show whilst ab block is on would be great. I don’t want to write exceptions or anything for my own viewing I want to set my page so that Adblock doesn’t block the images.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

1. I'm assuming that you're not talking about Adsense here but images hosted on your server and hard coded into your page.
2. If so they're probably being blocked because of the file name and/or path.

Adblock will block images

- with common ad dimensions in the file name, e.g. 'myimage_720_90.png' or 'myimage_300x250.jpg'.
- with common ad keywords in their path (and file name), e.g. *banners*, *adv*, *ad*.
- maybe other filters that analyse CSS or HTML

Check your image file names and rename some to see how it goes, try something generic like 'topwide.png or similar to avoid the filters.

Comment: +1 Great answer.  In my case, it was because I had the images in a '/banners/' directory, which was blocked.

Comment: Thanks for the +1 - a more complete original answer would have been be check the entire URI for strings that will trigger Adblock. Something like '/banners/myimage_720_90.png' will provide two matches to the blocker.

Comment: An addition to this, CSS selectors (e.g `class="advert banner etc"`) that was my case.

Comment: in my case the problem was the name of an image. it included the word 'facebook'

Comment: Image named `cahier_echo_doigt_600x350.jpg` was blocked.

Image named `cahier_echo_doigt-600x350.jpg` was not.

Comment: image name containing 120x60 was blocked as well on iPad with AdBlockPlus. In my case I just make image 120x61 or so as this is a Wordpress build and hard to get rid of img sizes from filenames

Comment: In my case, the file name (image) contained "share". Image was blocked as a result.

Comment: @Chaoley Really cool.. Recently I have used "admin-tools, ad-item" classes on my web app.. this causes to ad-blocker prevent my entire div  :p

Answer (score 8):

I had a very similar issue, I had some banners to display on an eCommerce site, put them im a folder called banners/size. After the page rendered, the banners would disappear in Chrome. I thought something was going crazy in JavaScript somewhere, I tried in Firefox and everything worked. Only difference, no AdBlock enabled in Firefox!

Inspecting the image statements, it had appended this to every image in the banners folder:

```
style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 1px 1px; width="0" height="0"
```

I renamed the banners folder to img_bnr, sorted!

Comment: Purchased a Drupal template years ago and the theme contained "banner" (`/sites/default/files/banner/`) in the image path for a jQuery text and image rotation plugin. Opera's new built-in ad-blocker was blocking the images from being downloaded for the same reason.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issue with filename like this:

`adv_s_imagesName.png` <-- Blocked by adblock because of "adv" in filename

for me "adv" mean "advanced" but for adblock it's "advertising"!

File renamed, no more block.

Answer (score 0):

Same here - had an image with 'adtech' in the name (abbreviation for advertising technology). Took me ages to figure out that adblocker was blocking because of the filename. Adtech being AOL's ad-serving platform. Understandable keyword to look out for, frustrating chasing you tail for ages trying to figure out why your content image is being blocked.

Comment: Look's like adblock worked as expected in your case then?