# Why does adblock block my images?

Tags: html, adblock

Adblock is blocking the images on the sponsors-page of our students-festival. I already looked into [StackOverflow: How to stop AdBlock plus blocking images in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255493/how-to-stop-adblock-plus-blocking-images-in-html-page) but renaming my images won't work for me, here's the HTML structure, maybe it has to do something with that?

```
<div id="sponsor-wrap">
    <h1>Sponsors</h1>                   
    <div class="sponsor-logo">
        <a href="http://www.21erhaus.at/" target="_blank">
            <img src="assets/img/21erHaus.jpg" alt="21er Haus" title="21er Haus">
        </a>
    </div>
    x20
</div>
```

Is there any resource about rules for preventing AdBlock blocking?

Comment: have a look at this page https://adblockplus.org/en/acceptable-ads

Comment: Try @Siderite Zackwehdex's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `sponsor-logo` class, which is inside a rule in [easylist](https://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/) list.